# How does a main.bicep file read bicep templates?

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem in an azure pipeline, which is giving me the error:

`[{"type":"TemplateViolation","info":{"lineNumber":1,"linePosition":1369,"path":"properties.template.resources[0]"}}]}]}}`

The bicep file it specifies at the start of this error doesn't have a position 1369, it's a short piece of comment that reads: //parameters.

Is the main.bicep reading all the template files as one large single line file and therefore position 1369 is actually the line number if I imagine all of the templates it references to be one large bicep? I'm just trying to narrow down where to start looking for the bug to try and fix the problem.

Comment: Is there not more detail you can share from the error?

Comment: you should check the deployments blade at the resource gorup level, it should give you more information on which module failed

Comment: I'm fairly sure I know which one is failing, i'm just hoping to work out which order it's failing in so I can use the line number to work out which line it's failing at to then try and fix the error

Comment: 1369 is the line number in the compiled JSON output from bicep.

I can do little more than guess when it comes down to debugging the error without seeing the IaC. Perhaps you can isolate the problem to a specific bicep module with the right param values?

Comment: If you have bicep extension, then you can build the bicep template in local which will generate ARM template. That template should have issue on line 1369